# Trouble displaying messages - basic Assembly bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

I'm a beginner Assembly programmer and I'm trying to write a basic secondary bootloader for a project of mine. Everything seems to work fine, excepting error handling: the program only prints "Starting the operating system..." on the screen, even if there are errors such as "Partition Table error!" or "Kernel partition cannot be found". I suspect that the starting message overwrite all the other messages, but I have trouble finding out why. I would appreciate some help!

I tried changing the cursor position and completely removing the "Starting the operating system" message, but no avail. (I'm testing my bootloader on a QEMU virtual machine)

```
ORG 0x8000
BITS 16

section .data
    buffer db 16 dup(0)
    pit_info db 16 dup(0)
    active_partition_info dw 0
 
section .text
    global start

start:
    mov ah, 0x00
    mov al, 0x03
    int 0x10
    mov si, starting_message
    call print
    mov ax, 0x8000
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, 0x01
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov dl, 0x80
    mov bx, buffer
    int 0x13
    jc error_missing_pit
    xor cx, cx
    mov si, buffer

loop:
    mov ax, [si + 0x1C]
    test ax, ax
    jnz found_bootable
    add si, 16
    inc cx
    cmp cx, 0
    jz no_bootable
    jmp loop

found_bootable:
    mov di, pit_info
    mov cx, 16
    rep movsb
    mov ax, [si + 0x08]
    mov [active_partition_info], ax
    mov ax, [si + 0x0C]
    mov [active_partition_info + 2], ax
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov bh, 0x00
    mov db 0x03
    mov dl, 0x00
    int 0x10
    mov si, partition_found_message
    call print 
    jmp kernel_load

error_missing_pit:
    mov si, missing_pit
    call print
    cli
    hlt

no_bootable:
    mov si, no_partition
    call print
    cli
    hlt

starting_message:
    db "Starting the operating system...", 0x0A, 0

missing_pit: 
     db "Partition Table error!", 0x0A, 0

no_partition:
     db "Kernel partition cannot be found - does it have the active flag?", 0x0A, 0

print:
    mov bx, 0
    call print_loop
    ret

print_loop:
    mov al, [si] 
    cmp al, 0 
    je print_done 
    mov ah, 0x0E 
    int 0x10 
    inc si 
    jmp print_loop

print_done:
    ret

kernel_load:
    ;.........

partition_found_message:
    db "Kernel partition found!", 0x0A, 0
```

Comment: `mov db 0x03`, should be `mov dh, 0x03`, this sets up cursor on the screen.

Comment: When computer starts all code is loaded always to `0x7c00` not `0x8000`. `ds = 0x0000, offset = 0x7c00`. In real mode addresses are calcuated in this way `segment * 16 + offset`.

Comment: @Nassau that's a secondary bootloader, not a primary bootloader. It's not mandatory for a secondary bootloader to run on 0x7C00 - that memory address is reserved for the primary bootloader.

Comment: You can use `stc` (set carry flag) after `ah = 0x02, int 0x13` just to see that `missing_pit` is printed on the screen. Also bootloaders shoud end with `magic number`. `times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0`, `dw 0xAA55. Qemu will show `no bootable device` if this number is missing.

Comment: @Nassau Thank you. I will try this and tell you if it worked. Btw, the magic number is only required for the primary bootloader - secondary bootloader doesn't need a magic number because the secondary doesn't care about it as long as it is configured to load it from the correct disk sector and jump to the appropriate memory address.

Comment: @Nassau I changed to mov dh, 0x03 and also triggered a forced error using the set carry flag as you told me, but the bootloader still doesn't output anything excepting "Loading the operating system...". That's confusing.

Comment: Well you print out `starting_message` and since it prints I assume DS was correct at the start of execution of  the Volume Boot Record. But then after that you set DS to 0x8000 which means from that point on when you try to print things out at memory address `SI` (in print) you will be trying to print strings from 0x8000:xxxx rather than from 0x0000:0x8xxx. Maybe before calling `print` you should set DS back to 0?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you so much. It seems that that was the issue. Now my code prints messages correctly.

Comment: Unrelated to your questions. Did you write a primary bootloader as well (I mean one that is in the Master Boot Record)?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Of course, that's a common practice. My s. bootloader is too large to fit on a 446 byte space (+2 for the magic number and +64 for the Partition Table). So I made a simple primary bootloader to load the secondary bootloader to get over this limitation.